# loopback authenticating rest api url

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

i have created an endpoint to download csv file but i want to authenticate the endpoint before download, i.e. it should ask for username and password and if verified then only download of csv should happen. i want to do it with loopback only. Any help appreciated. Thanku.

my code for csv download-

```
Transaction.csvexport = function(type, res, callback) {
     res.set('Content-Type','application/download');
     res.set('Content-Disposition','attachment;filename=Data.csv');
     res.set('Content-Transfer-Encoding','binary');
     res.send('ok;'); //@todo: insert CSV data here.
   };
   Transaction.remoteMethod('csvexport',
   {
     accepts: [
       {arg: 'type', type: 'string', required: true },
       {arg: 'res', type: 'object', 'http': {source: 'res'}}
     ],
     returns: {},
     http: {path: '/csvexport/:type', verb: 'get'}
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

Authentication is not enabled by default on Loopback. You can create users and set ACLs with the framework. Check out the [documentation](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Authentication-authorization-and-permissions.html) for more info.